# Как добавить свой текст при копировании в буфер обмена?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу сделать чтобы когда человек на моем сайте копирует какой-либо текст, чтобы автоматически в конец с новой строки добавлялся мой тест. И при этом чтобы абзацы были сохранены. Например:

--скопированный текст---

МОЙ ТЕКСТ

Comment: как же не люблю я такие сайты. Как будто у всех на столько уникальнейший контент, что там милллионы стоит всё >_<

Comment: Мне тоже кажется, что лучше так не делать. Люди часто копируют не для того, чтобы цитировать, но чтобы, например, искать в интернете или словарях. Очень раздражает, когда в таких случаях приходится вычищать ссылки и т.п. Да и вообще любое нарушение предсказуемого и привычного  не на пользу чувствам пользователя к сайту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например вот так можно:

```js
function addLink() {
  var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  //Итоговый скопированный текст
  var copytext = selection + "\n" + document.location.href;
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
  newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';
  body_element.appendChild(newdiv);
  newdiv.innerText = copytext;
  selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    body_element.removeChild(newdiv);
  }, 0);
}

document.oncopy = addLink;
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```